# Executing code when application is killed by TaskManager or CMD

Tags: c#, mysql, get, httpwebrequest

I am making a remote administration tool for my laptop, so I can access it via a web interface whenever I go somewhere.

I was wondering if I could execute the following code whenever the application is killed by Task Manager or CMD/Powershell:

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create($"http://10.0.0.1/?p=Logout&HOSTNAME={HOSTNAME}&IP={IP}&USERNAME={USERNAME}&HASH={HASH}");
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse());
```

(HOSTNAME, IP, USERNAME and HASH are variables)

This would be executed so that my laptop is de-registered from my database.

P.S I know it is vulnerable to SQL injection, but I'll fix it later.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the way your application is killed however you can cover a lot of this. im sure it works for taskmanager however a TerminateProcess and certainly in Kernel mode can be a pain, not that, that would be the case i guess. here's a example:

```
private delegate bool ConsoleEventDelegate(int eventType);

public static Main(string[] args)
{
            SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleEventCallback, true);
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += Reset;
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += Exit;
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload += Exit;
}

        private static void Exit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create($"http://10.0.0.1/?p=Logout&HOSTNAME={HOSTNAME}&IP={IP}&USERNAME={USERNAME}&HASH={HASH}");
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse());
        }

        private static void Reset(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            Exit(null, null);
        }

        private static bool ConsoleEventCallback(int eventType = 0)
        {
            Exit(null, null);
            return false;
        }
```